Difficulty setting series data on an apexchart for a Vue Composition api component
I've just retired and I've been trying to teach myself Vue and Python as hobby by writing a front-end (Vuetify) and back-end (DRF) to monitor our energy usage and cost. It's been a challenge but all my CRUD functionality to maintain supplier, contract, tariff and meter reading data is working. Now I want to show the gas and net electricity use and how much the solar panels have generated in a chart. I think I'm fairly close and would be very grateful if someone could take a look at the following files and show me what I'm missing. They're not so long so I posted all the code.
ReadingChart.vue is my component to display the chart:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted,computed, onBeforeMount } from "vue";
import { getPrimary, getSecondary } from '@/utils/UpdateColors';
import { useMeterStore } from '@/stores/apps/meter';

const store = useMeterStore();

const getChartYears: any = computed(() => {
    return store.years;
});

const getChartGas: any = computed(() => {
    return store.gas;
});
const getChartStand_i: any = computed(() => {
    return store.stand_i;
});
const getChartstand_ii: any = computed(() => {
    return store.stand_ii;
});

let chart_years = ref(getChartYears);
let chart_gas = ref(getChartGas);
let chart_stand_i = ref(getChartStand_i);
let chart_stand_ii = ref(getChartstand_ii);

/*Chart*/
const chartOptions = computed(() => {
    return {
      grid: {
      show: false,
      borderColor: "transparent",
      padding: { left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
    },

    plotOptions: {
      bar: { horizontal: false, columnWidth: "35%", borderRadius: 0 },
    },

    colors: [getPrimary.value,getSecondary.value],
    fill: { type: "solid", opacity: 1 },
    
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
      height: 320,
      offsetX: -15,
      toolbar: { show: false },
      foreColor: "#adb0bb",
      fontFamily: "Poppins",
      sparkline: { enabled: false },
    },
    
    dataLabels: { enabled: false },
    markers: { size: 0 },
    legend: { show: false },
    
    xaxis: {
      type: "category",
      categories: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chart_years.value)),
      // categories: ["2015","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022","2023","2024"],
      labels: {
        style: { cssClass: "grey--text lighten-2--text fill-color" },
      },
    },
    
    yaxis: {
      show: true,
      min: 100,
      max: 3500,
      tickAmount: 3,
      labels: {
        style: {
          cssClass: "grey--text lighten-2--text fill-color",
        },
      },
    },
    stroke: {
      show: true,
      width: 5,
      lineCap: "butt",
      colors: ["transparent"],
    },
    tooltip: { theme: "dark" },
    };
});

let Chart = ref({
  series: [
    { name: "gas_data", data: [] },
    { name: "stand_i_data", data: [] },
    { name: "stand_ii_data", data: [] },
  ],
});

const elementVisible = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
  store.fetchChartData();
  
const Chart = ref({
  series: [
    // { name: "gas_data", data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chart_gas.value)) },
    { name: "gas_data", data: ["17.0","2.01","706.11","549.25","584.65","315.86","304.04",
"123.97"] },
    { name: "stand_i_data", data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chart_stand_i.value)) },
    { name: "stand_ii_data", data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chart_stand_ii.value))},
  ],
});

  setTimeout(() => (elementVisible.value = true), 50);
});
</script>

<template>
  <!-- ------------------------------------ -->
  <!-- html -->
  <!-- ------------------------------------ -->
<VCard elevation="10">
    <v-card-text>
      <div class="d-sm-flex align-center">
        <div>
          <h3 class="text-h5 title mb-1">Sales Overview</h3>
          <h5 class="text-subtitle-1">Ample Admin Vs Pixel Admin</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
          <div class="d-flex align-center">
            <div class="d-flex align-center px-2">
              <span class="text-primary">
                <span class="text-overline">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-brightness-1 mx-1"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="font-weight-regular">Ample</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex align-center px-2">
              <span class="text-secondary">
                <span class="text-overline">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-brightness-1 mx-1"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="font-weight-regular">Pixel Admin</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-show="elementVisible" class="mt-5">
        <apexchart
        type="bar" height="320" :options="chartOptions" :series="Chart.series"
        ></apexchart>
      </div>
    </v-card-text>
  </VCard>
</template>

meter.ts is my store where I fetch the data from the database
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
// project imports
import axios from 'axios';
const baseApiUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_DRF_API_URL}`;
const url = `${import.meta.env.VITE_DRF_API_URL}/api/reading/`;

export const useMeterStore = defineStore({
    id: 'Meter',
    state: () => ({
        meter_readings: [],
        chart_data: {},
        years: [], 
        gas: [], 
        stand_i: [], 
        stand_ii: [], 
    }),
    getters: {},
    actions: {
        // Fetch followers from action
        async fetchMeterReadings() {
            try {
                const headers = get_headers();
                const response = await axios.get(url, {headers}).then(request => request.data);
                this.meter_readings = response.data;
            } catch (error) {
                // alert(error);
                console.log(error);
            }
        },
        async fetchChartData() {
            try {
                const headers = get_headers();
                let customUrl = baseApiUrl + "/api/readingchart?year=all";
                await axios.get(customUrl, {headers}).then(
                    request => {
                        this.years = request.data.data.years;
                        this.gas = request.data.data.gas;
                        this.stand_i = request.data.data.stand_i;
                        this.stand_ii = request.data.data.stand_ii;
                    } 
                )
            } catch (error) {
                // alert(error);
                console.log(error);
            }
        },
        async updateMeterReading(reading: {
                id: string; consumption_date: string; stand_i: string; stand_ii: string; gas: string;
            }){
            try {
                let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
                const headers = get_headers();
                await axios.put(url + reading.id + "/", reading, {headers}) .then(request => request.data);
            } 
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
});

function get_headers() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + token,
    };
    return headers;
}

The reason I said I thought I was close was that when the application is running and I make a change in VS Code by commenting out one of the lines of code in the Chart object series property or on the x-axis category (see code) and saving then the chart is displayed. If I run it again then the chart disappears and so I go around in circles. I cant figure it out. I guess I'm not quite there yet with Vue reactivity and I'd appreciate any help. I'm using node 20.12.2 and @vue/cli 5.0.8.
Edit. I just noticed that if I navigate to another page and then navigate back then chart is also displayed. Its just the initial page load that's not working.

That Vue CLI was a bad choice. Please consider using the Vite one for Vue3 to avoid a lot of issues (or are you already using it?). Otherwise, do you have any errors in your console when the whole thing disappears? What about your Vue devtools? Not sure how VScode is a concern here, is your state poorly populated or is it a Hot Module Reload issue? Your chartOptions is quite a big computed, maybe the issue comes from here? Prefer not using hacks like setTimeout.

@kissu Nothing wrong with Vue CLI, it's not very future-proof but workable. That it works on save looks exactly like a side effect of hot reload, pinia requires additional steps to support it in webpack setups (which vue cli is),  https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/hot-module-replacement.html

@user3623116 You have race condition, you're trying to access store data that is not there on initial render. Don't render this component until fetchChartData is finished. There are several ways to do this in vue 3. The easy one is await store.fetchChartData() in the body of setup instead of mounted(), and ReadingChart should be used inside  because this makes it asynchronous

@EstusFlask at the same time he is using import.meta.env.VITE_DRF_API_URL, hence why I am confused about which bundler is used: Webpack or Vite.

Thanks EstusFlask. I did as you suggested and it worked. Very much appreciated.
